# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException -- Twitter Client for Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, client

I using a tutorial from tutsplus.com on building a twitter client for Android.  I've built the entire application and when I run it, the following error appears in logcat for Eclipse.

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException -- reading a few things, it has to deal with the API level I'm calling. Currently I'm building for 4.0.3 which is API 15. After API 11, you are not allowed to do network calls in the same thread as the UI. The reason behind this is not to stall or crash the UI.  Networking calls must be in an AsyncTask or Service.

Long and short of my question/problem/issue is that the tutorial maker is of no help to correct the problem, so that's why I'm here.  I'm posting the code below, in hopes that someone can help me move the network portion into an AsyncTask or Service.

```
package com.jasonsdesign.tweetxy;

import twitter4j.ProfileImage;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.auth.RequestToken;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TweetxyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

/**developer account key for this app*/
public final static String TWIT_KEY = "";
/**developer secret for the app*/
public final static String TWIT_SECRET = "";
/**app url*/
public final static String TWIT_URL = "tweetxy-android:///";

private String LOG_TAG = "TweetxyActivity";

/**Twitter instance*/
private Twitter tweetxyTwitter;
/**request token for accessing user account*/
private RequestToken tweetxyRequestToken;
/**shared preferences to store user details*/
private SharedPreferences tweetxyPrefs;
/**main view for the home timeline*/
private ListView homeTimeline;
/**database helper for update data*/
private TweetxyDataHelper timelineHelper;
/**update database*/
private SQLiteDatabase timelineDB;
/**cursor for handling data*/
private Cursor timelineCursor;
/**adapter for mapping data*/
private UpdateAdapter timelineAdapter;
/**broadcast receiver for when new updates are available*/
private BroadcastReceiver tweetxyStatusReceiver;

//set the profile image display
ProfileImage.ImageSize imageSize = ProfileImage.NORMAL;

/*
 * onCreate behaves differently on first run and subsequent runs
 * - if first run take to Twitter sign in page to grant the app permission
 * - subsequent runs fetch and present the user home timeline
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //get the preferences
    tweetxyPrefs = getSharedPreferences("TweetxyPrefs", 0);
    //find out if the user preferences are set
    if(tweetxyPrefs.getString("user_token", null)==null) {
            //no user preferences so prompt to sign in
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //get a twitter instance for authentication
        tweetxyTwitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            //pass developer key and secret
        tweetxyTwitter.setOAuthConsumer(TWIT_KEY, TWIT_SECRET);
            //try to get request token
        try 
        {
                //get authentication request token
            tweetxyRequestToken = tweetxyTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWIT_URL);
        }
        catch(TwitterException te) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "TE "+te.getMessage()); }
        //setup button for click listener
        Button signIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signin);
        signIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    else 
    {
        //user preferences are set - get timeline
        setupTimeline();
    }

}

/**
 * Click listener handles sign in and tweet button presses
 */
public void onClick(View v) {
    //find view
    switch(v.getId()) {
        //sign in button pressed
    case R.id.signin:
            //take user to twitter authentication web page to allow app access to their twitter account
        String authURL = tweetxyRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authURL)));
        break;
        //user has pressed tweet button
    case R.id.tweetbtn:
            //launch tweet activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, TweetxyTweet.class));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

/*
 * onNewIntent fires when user returns from Twitter authentication Web page
 */
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //get the retrieved data
    Uri twitURI = intent.getData();
    //make sure the url is correct
    if(twitURI!=null && twitURI.toString().startsWith(TWIT_URL)) 
    {
        //is verification - get the returned data
        String oaVerifier = twitURI.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
        //attempt to retrieve access token
        try
        {
                //try to get an access token using the returned data from the verification page
            AccessToken accToken = tweetxyTwitter.getOAuthAccessToken(tweetxyRequestToken, oaVerifier);
                //add the token and secret to shared prefs for future reference
            tweetxyPrefs.edit()
                .putString("user_token", accToken.getToken())
                .putString("user_secret", accToken.getTokenSecret())
                .commit();
                //display the timeline
            setupTimeline();

        }
        catch (TwitterException te)
        { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to get access token: "+te.getMessage()); }
    }
}

/**
 * setupTimeline displays the user's main home Twitter timeline
 */

private void setupTimeline() {

    //set the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.timeline);
        //setup onclick listener for tweet button
    LinearLayout tweetClicker = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tweetbtn);
    tweetClicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        //retrieve the timeline
    try 
    {
            //get reference to the list view
        homeTimeline = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.homeList);
            //instantiate database helper
        timelineHelper = new TweetxyDataHelper(this);
            //get the database
        timelineDB = timelineHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        //query the database, most recent tweets first
        timelineCursor = timelineDB.query("home", null, null, null, null, null, "update_time DESC");
        //manage the updates using a cursor
        startManagingCursor(timelineCursor);
        //instantiate adapter
        timelineAdapter = new UpdateAdapter(this, timelineCursor);
        //apply the adapter to the timeline view
        //this will make it populate the new update data in the view
        homeTimeline.setAdapter(timelineAdapter);
        //instantiate receiver class for finding out when new updates are available
        tweetxyStatusReceiver = new TwitterUpdateReceiver();
        //register for updates
        registerReceiver(tweetxyStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter("TWITTER_UPDATES"));

        //start the service for updates now
        this.getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), TimelineService.class));
    }
    catch(Exception te) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to fetch timeline: "+te.getMessage()); }
}

/**
 * Class to implement broadcast receipt for new updates
 */
class TwitterUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    /**
     * When new updates are available, a broadcast is received here
     */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //delete db rows
        int rowLimit = 100;
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(timelineDB, "home")>rowLimit) {
            String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM home WHERE "+BaseColumns._ID+" NOT IN " +
                    "(SELECT "+BaseColumns._ID+" FROM home ORDER BY "+"update_time DESC " +
                            "limit "+rowLimit+")";  
            timelineDB.execSQL(deleteQuery);
        }       

        timelineCursor = timelineDB.query("home", null, null, null, null, null, "update_time DESC");
        startManagingCursor(timelineCursor);
        timelineAdapter = new UpdateAdapter(context, timelineCursor);
        homeTimeline.setAdapter(timelineAdapter);
    }
}

/*
 * When the class is destroyed, close database and service classes
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try 
    {
        //stop the updater service
        stopService(new Intent(this, TimelineService.class));
        //remove receiver register
        unregisterReceiver(tweetxyStatusReceiver);
        //close the database
        timelineDB.close();
    }
    catch(Exception se) { Log.e(LOG_TAG, "unable to stop service or receiver"); }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, asking people to rewrite your code for you typically doesn't happen unless you show some effort on how you tried to do it, and why it's not working.  In this case, yes, AsyncTask is what you want to do, and it's got nothing to do with API level, you should never do network operations on any main thread in any framework ever.

Comment: It does crash now with an NetworkOnMainThreadException. I suppose it has something to do with Android 4.0 and the targetSDKVersion beeing to high. Yes it is bad practice to do networking on the UI Thread.

Comment: @Dirk  How can targetSDKVersion be too high?  They are always backwards compatible, or you can use the compatibility package.

Comment: Setting the targetSdkVersion to a certain value will disable compatibility behaviour in newer devices.

Answer (score 3):

What do you need besides what https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html provides? Do you have a specific question regarding the usage of AsyncTask?

You take the offending line and put it inside doInBackground(). If it has a result you either put the result handling code in doInBackground(), if it does not manipulate the UI. If it does make changes to the UI, you put it in onPostExecute().

Then you replace the line that threw the exception with:

new MyTask().execute(param);

Keep in mind that the code after this is executed immediately.

Comment: With regards to Twitter4j, your suggestion will result in:
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)

Comment: Please rephrase. I guess you get an Exception but I can't see it in your incomplete stacktrace.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that Twitter4j errors that have to do with NetworkOnMainUiThread aren't solved easily with just an AsyncTask.  There may have to potentially be many asynctasks as well as onPostExecute methods.  Have you done troubleshooting with Twitter4j?

Comment: I have not used Twitter4j recently. I have no idea how may places need reworking with AsyncTasks to not throw NetworkOnMainThreadExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for your question to be held up, most of the issues you face at the moment are solvable through the AsyncTask use that is so well documented over [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
I'd suggest you don't use the tutorial as a framework to your app/project but rather use it as a guide to know how to set your own project up. It'll be way better if you create your own AsyncTask and use that to get data from the network as getting network related data in a main task or most tasks besides AsynTasks is usually frowned upon due to the exceptions it throws.